# Is there a way to de-fuse weapons?

Tags: zelda-tears-of-the-kingdom

Sometimes I want to de-fuse a weapon because I've found a better component I want to add, or a better weapon to use that component. Is there a way to de-fuse a weapon or shield?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to un-fuse a weapon, you can select the "Destroy Fused Material" option in the item menu, but **you will lose the item you fused to it**:

> [Y]ou can always go into the item menu, select the weapon you’ve Fused, and select the “Destroy Fused Material” option. This will demolish the item attached to the weapon you’ve used as a base, though, so keep that in mind before resorting to this method.

If you want to **keep the item you fused to the weapon**, there is a way,  but you need to reach a certain point in the game it seems (small spoilers):

> There is a Goron named Pelison in Tarrey Town that you can pay 20 rupees to unfuse items:

Source quotes:

> > Fusing isn’t permanent. If you find yourself using a rare material like a diamond on a stick by accident, you can actually detach the two, preserving both materials. This can only be done once you complete the Great Sky Island, however
> >  
> >  In Tarrey Town, head over to Pelison, the Goron child in the city square, to Unfuse your weapons and get those precious materials back. It will cost 20 rupees to Unfuse any weapon. This is also the only way we’ve found so far to Unfuse weapons while keeping the Fused item intact, by the way

([Source](https://www.polygon.com/zelda-tears-of-the-kingdom-guide/23717512/how-to-un-fuse-weapons))

Comment: Does this also work with weapons found on the ground that are already fused with something? I don't have a specific example, but often I found a weapon and I can't fuse it because it's already fused with something

Comment: @Wondercricket are you asking if you can remove the fused item found on a weapon on the ground?  I don't have the game to try myself, but I'm sure you can test this pretty easily using both of the methods described in my answer.

Comment: Can you have Pelison unfuse the sapphire/ruby/topaz swords wielded by wizrobes?